# Does zaqat is obligatory on property,household item,personal belonging other than gold, silver and currency?

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, zakat

In our society mostly zakat is given on gold currency and crops.what is the exact teaching of Islam.Is zakat is obligatory on property and other personal belongings???